# Which scripture contains sri datta stavam?

Tags: stotra, dattatreya

Is [sri datta stavam](http://www.vishwamatha.com/sri-datta-stavam.html) a part of any scripture? If yes, what is the name of the scripture? Else, who wrote it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [**this**](http://forum.spiritualindia.org/your-experience-with-sai-baba/the-power-of-datta-stavam-a-powerful-stotra/) blog article **Shri Datta Stavam** is composed by [**Shri Vasudevanand Saraswathy**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasudevanand_Saraswati)  (Tembe swamy 1854–1914).This stotra is also having another name as "Jaya Laabhaadhikara Shree Dattastavam".

Which is having 9 shlokas.  As we can see this stotra is fairly new one and is not part of any ancient hinduism scriptures.
I am herewith posting the sanskrit shlokas of Datta Stavam , the meaning of which can be found on [**Hindudharmaforums**](http://hindudharmaforums.com/showthread.php?15333-Datta-Stavam) site. Its believed among Shri Datta devotees
that reciting this stotra a person gets Wealth , peace of mind , success , material desires and ultimately Moksha.

---

Datta Stavam

> 1. Dattatreyam mahatmanam varadam bhakta vatsalam 
>     Prapannarthi haram vande smartrgami Sanovatu
> 2. Dinabandum Krpasindhum sarvakarana karanam
>     Sarva raksakaram vande smartrgami sanovatu
> 3. Saranagata dinarta paritrana parayanam
>     Narayanam vibhum vande smartrgami sanovatu
> 4. Sarvanartha haram devam sarva mangala mangalam
>     Sarvaklesa haram vande smartrgami sanovatu
> 5. Brahmanyam dharma tattvajnam bhakta kirti vivardhanam
>     Bhaktabhista pradam vande smartrgami sanovatu
> 6. Sosanam papapankasya dipanam jnanatejasah
>     Tapa prasamanam vande smartrgami sanovatu
> 7. Sarvaroga prasamanam sarvapida nivaranam
>     Vipaduddharanam vande smartrgami sanovatu
> 8. Janmasamsara bandhajnam svarupananda dayakam
>     Nissreyasa padam vande smartrgami sanovatu
> 9. Jaya labha yasah kama datu rdattasya yastavam
>     Bhogamoksha prada syemam prapathet sakriti bhavet

Comment: The language in your link is Kannada i think , but i have crosschecked the shlokas in your link by google translate and found to be same with 9 shlokas as mentioned by various other sites.

Comment: ha, it is Telugu...

Comment: Oh ok , i don't know both but anyway you can crosscheck whether the stotra is same or not by reading and pls. let me know if both are different in case.

Comment: (Y)............