# Vande smartrgami Sanovatu in Datta Stavam

Tags: dattatreya, meaning, stava

There are nine stanzas in [Datta Stavam](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/34927/661).

All the stanzas except the last one ends with **vande Smarthrugaami Sanovathu**.

What is the meaning of that and what is its connection with Dattatreya?

Answer (score 5):

The complete stotra, translated into English, is available on the [Hindupedia.com](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Sri_Datta_Sthavam) website.

Quoting from there:

> Dathathreyam Mahathmanam,
>  Varadam Bhaktha Vathsalam,
> Prapannarthi haram **vande,
>  Smarthrugaami Sanovathu**., 1
>
> **Salutations to** Dathathreya who is a great one, Who loves and blesses his devotees, And who destroys all worries of those,
> **Who always remember him with faith.**

You can see how another stanza is translated.

> Deenabandhum, krupasindhum,
>  Sarva Karana Kaaranaam,
>  Sarva
> Raksha karam **vande,
>  Smarthrugaami Sanovathu**., 2
>
> **Salutations to** the friend of the oppressed, Who is the ocean of mercy, Who is the cause of all causes, And who protects all those,
> **Who always remember him with faith.**

Therefore, the required meanings are:

Vande - Salutations (to) and Smarthrugaami Sanovathu - Who always remember him with faith.

Answer (score 3):

**Vande**- I bow down to this revered Lord

**Smaṛtṛgāmi sano’vatu**- May that Lord who responds instantly when **thought of**!

---

**Datta** indicates gifting.

Atri and Anasuya did austerities to beget son, for the benefit of the world.  The Almighty God, **gifted itself** to that couple in the form of a child.  That is Datta. He being the son of Atri, was known as dattAtrEya.

---

The Almighty God resides in everyone.  The concept is that the God, being the resident in everyone, need not be called loudly for response, but mere **thinking** of is sufficient.  So the word **Smaṛtṛgāmi**

Comment: sano’vatu means protect us all?

Comment: as far as I understood, it is Saha+Aanavathu=Sanovathu.  " Smarthrugaami Sanovathu "  means " One who comes the instant one is thought of " .   I have edited my answer. @hanugm